# how could I update only one cell in HBase?

Tags: python, hbase

I have a HTable with 100,000 rows, each rows has 30,000 columns in average.

There is a process which update one of the cell(one row's one column).

for example:

```
row1   cf:1=2  cf:2=2  cf:3=4  cf:4=1 ... cf:30000=1
```

I only need to update `row1's cf:3 from 4 to 5(add 1)`

how could I update the table?

does hbase has some update function like mysql's :

```
update `testtable` set `cf3`=`cf3`+1 where row='row1';
```

I wrote the program using python. and now I use getRow to get all the row, which is very slow. then modify the value, and then put back to htable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use put to "over write" old value.
Or delete old value first, put new value.

Or if you want this feature when do codinging or testing,
https://github.com/zhang-xzhi/simplehbaseviewer

you can use such statement to update your data in hbase.
insert into MyRecordV05 ( name,age ) values ( "allen", "30" ) rowkey is intkey ("0")

Answer (score 0):

There is no update command like RDBMs in HBase. But you could write a small program to do that. There could be 2 ways, either delete the current value and then put the new value or simply put the new value as a new version. If you are comfortable with Java you could use **[deleteColumn()](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Delete.html#deleteColumn%28byte%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D%29)** to delete the value of a specified column directly.